# ESP32 struggling to trigger relay module consistently

Tags: esp32, relay, voltage-level, electronics

I'm working with a 4-channel, 5 V relay module and an ESP32 which operates on 3.3 V.

[image]

The setup seemed to work well initially  but I have started experiencing some inconsistencies. One of the four relays is working perfectly fine, but the other three are not triggering as they should.

Here are the symptoms:

- The LEDs on the non-working relays do light up when a signal is sent from the ESP32, indicating some form of communication.
- There is no audible 'click' sound from these relays when they are supposed to trigger.
  I noticed that if I gently tap the relay casing, the relay will sometimes trigger, and I can hear it closing.

I had previously thought that I might have fried my first relay module, so I replaced it, but the issue reappeared after a few days.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Is your relay board compatible with 3.3 V logic?

Comment: @StarCat i don't understand your question can you help me figure out or explain a bit more it's supposed to be powered by 5V DC but i'm limited to the esp32 board

Comment: Maybe it is your code.  Try posting a small example that reproduces the problem

Comment: More questions here then you might think are because of under powered project using fresh but weak batteries.  Almost always avoid using 9 Volt batteries.  Certainly avoid them if a motor or relay is involved.  How is this project powered?

Comment: right now i'm using the usb type-C cable to power the esp directly how can i make the esp32 generate more power or make the relay use less current to be triggered

Comment: do not use the ESP32 as a power supply ... it can easily become an expensive fuse ... use it for control only ... power the relay module from a separate power supply

Comment: With "compatible with 3.3 V logic" I mean: does your relay board work with 3.3 V logic signals *according to its documentation*?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that esp32 boards can actually output 5v alongside with 3.3v output pin, You just have to use the VN pin which is used for powering the board when not connected through USB, this is not what the pin is intended for and also might cause some problems and you cannot upload code to the board when VIN pin is connected but so far it works perfectly and outputs consistent 5V that triggers the relays just fine.

Obviously, I was just looking for a solution no matter what risks it imposed, can anyone with a deeper understanding of this topic explain why the power input pin can also work as output and why is this not a feature that comes with esp32 boards

Comment: Hi Hach, The way this site works is one question followed by answers.  You edit the original question to provide more information.  Or you ask a new question separately.

Comment: i answered the original question but asked if the solution i found is efficient and if it presents any dangers to the board